# Ignore any scaling policy when the current number of instance or service is already at original minimum count?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-ecs

Is there a way to ignore any scaling policy whenever I have reached the lowest - the desired count before any autoscaling was triggered?

**Assumption**

- I have alarms to trigger scaling in or out instances of my cluster.
- any scaling in/out only scales 1 instance at a time.

**Scenario**

1. Original instance count in a cluster is: **2**
2. an alarm was triggered based on a specific metric to trigger scale out policy - scale out 1 instance
3. instance count now is **3**
4. after sometime due to decrease of usage, an alarm triggers to scale in my cluster - scaling in 1 instance.
5. instance count now back to **2**
6. There are no current traffic/usages/requests directed to my cluster now and that, an alarm will trigger to scale in thus, leaving my cluster to scale in another instance resulting to **1** instance count at the stage. I would want it to only trigger any scaling in if **instance count > 2**

**Is the only way to do this, is by load testing my cluster to determine the suitable average threshold(percentage) my cluster will experience in production?**

Scaling out **based on the number of requests** our application is receiving but when scaling in basing on number of requests leads to this issue.

Comment: Use a Lambda function to control scaling activity based on CloudWatch Alarms.

Comment: Are you scaling the autoscaling group based on ECS Metrics?

Comment: I think with lambda we can do anything as long as the sdk allows. But we might end up having to update the code, which I think requires more trial and error specially on checking if it works without bugs on production since we can't find any local environment to test the function with the actual aws resources. So for now, we are leaning towards basing the scaling policies with the ECS Metrics - for example, the RequestCount Metric